# Unset cookies php

Tags: php, cookies

I have this code that setted when login check is fine:

```
if((isset($_POST["remember_me"]))&&($_POST["remember_me"]==1))
    {
    setcookie('email', $username, time()+3600);
    setcookie('pass', $pass, time()+3600);
    }
```

Now, when I click on logout link (logout.php)
i did this:

```
<?php session_start();
setcookie("email", '', 1, "");
setcookie("pass", '', 1, "");
$_SESSION["login"] = "";
header("location: aforum/enter_furom.php");
?>
```

I didn't use destroy session because I don't want to destroy all sessions....
now destroying a session is working fine... but when I try to unset cookies, the browsers (all browsers: explorer, chrome, firefox, mozilla) give me an error saying that *the new cookies cant be setted*...any help to unset the above cookies ?

Comment: Almost there, but you didn't actually say what _actually happens_ to the browser- are the cookies retained? Changed in some way?

Comment: You might find [`$cookie->delete()`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Cookie/blob/004cde69ec840e65c15275e09b92ecb1da06f357/src/Cookie.php#L173) helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Cookie).

Answer (score 19):

either use the superglobal `_COOKIE` variable:

```
unset($_COOKIE['mycookiename']);
```

or call `setcookie()` with **only** the cookies name

```
setcookie('mycookiename');
```

To reset your cookies at logout use:

```
setcookie('pass');
setcookie('email');
```

For you login check:

```
if(
  isset($_POST["remember_me"]) &&
  $_POST["remember_me"]==1  &&
  $_COOKIE['pass'] != NULL &&
  $_COOKIE['email'] != NULL &&
)
```

Comment: still not working...the new error gives me: the redirect(header location...) is had been did very times...so or to delete cookies from my pc or a server problem...but when i remove cookies from pc...it works again...and when logout...the same problem... :\

Comment: are you sure the cookie isn't reset after it has been deleted and the client forwarded via header()?

Comment: yeah man its set...i knew what is my problem...my problem...that in my check,....

`if((isset($_COOKIE["email"]))&&(isset($_COOKIE["pass"])))
 {
 $_SESSION["login"] =1 ;
 }`
.. now how can i do in this check not only if isset email...but only email for example !=1 ?

Comment: you mean `if((isset($_COOKIE["email"]))&&$_COOKIE["email"]!=1&&(isset($_COOKIE["pass"]))) { $_SESSION["login"] =1 ; }` ?

Comment: yes..and the pass != ,,,, AND!!!-> how to set in the logout..pass cookies and email cookies that = 1 ?

Comment: not sure what you want.. this should be obvious.. but look at the edits to my answer. you should be able to write something like this yourself tho. :S

Comment: This is wrong, use one of the other answers. The super global is populated from the HTTP headers and manipulating it will have no effect on the client. The documentation doesn't state `setcookie` can be used in that manner to delete a cookie either.

Comment: mm look..i have 4 files: 1 . the form.php... if checked (remember me) sends in post value  = 1 ... now .. the second file..the login.php...if remember_me = 1 .. set cookies email,pass....and the login check..the third file: index.php ->  `if(($_COOKIE['email'] != NULL)&&($_COOKIE['pass'] != NULL))
 {
 $_SESSION["login"] =1 ;
 }
 if($_SESSION["login"]!=1)
 {
 header("location: form.php");
 }` 
4 . logout.php : `<?php session_start();
setcookie('emaildevz');
setcookie('passdevz');
$_SESSION["login"] = "";
header("location: aforum/enter_furom.php");
?>`...in unset the cookies theere are a problem

Comment: THANK YOU @Gung Foo .... i solved my problem......the name of the cookies wasnt match what in the log

Answer (score 12):

```
setcookie('cookiename', '', time()-3600);
```

Answer (score 3):

Just set the value of cookie to `false` in order to unset it,

```
setcookie('cookiename', false);
```

That's the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Check in your browser for the directory where the cookie operates. And unset it by specify the path the cookie have. Like in the example if the cookie directory is `/aforum/`

```
setcookie ("email","",time()-1,"/aforum/","http:// yourdomain.com");
```

Comment: the manual suggests `time() - 3600` but -1 or -9999 are also as crazy. why do people use a call to time() at all? why no just type the time equivalent of 1st jan 1970?

Answer (score 1):

To unset cookies in PHP, simply set their expiry time to a time in the past. For example:

```
$expire = time() - 300;
setcookie("email", '', $expire);
setcookie("pass", '', $expire);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    setcookie ("email", "", time() - 3600);
    setcookie ("pass", "", time() - 3600);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your expire time to the past, e.g.

```
setcookie('email', '', time()-3600);
```

Also you should be using an `Absolute URI` for your `header('Location:' ....)`.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome and IE8+ at least, the following will remove the cookie from the browser.  It will not be reflected in the `$_COOKIE` array until the page is reloaded however.

`setcookie('cookiename','',0,'/',$cookieDomain)`

you may be able to leave off a few parameters here, but the important thing is you are setting an empty string, and that removes the cookie from the browser.

Comment: This code should not remove the cookie from the browser. According to the [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php): "[expires parameter] If set to 0, or omitted, the cookie will expire at the end of the session (when the browser closes)."

Comment: @MarkMessa for all practical purposes, it is deleted when set with no value.  It will exist in the browser with `no value` until the session is ended, after expire time is reached.

Answer (score 0):

```
unset($_COOKIE['MYCOOKIE']);
//
setcookie('MYCOOKIE', '', -1, '/');
```

Care for `header` **"Cannot modify header information.."** you can also
use `html` or `javascript` for redirect

```
header("Location: /");
//
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=/">';
//
echo '<script>window.location.replace("/");</script>';
```

I prefer to check with `isset` and than `unset | setcookie`

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['MYCOOKIE'])) { unset($_COOKIE['MYCOOKIE']); }
//
if(isset($_COOKIE['MYCOOKIE'])) { setcookie('MYCOOKIE', '', -1, '/'); }
```

this seems to work too, but don't use it in my opinion

```
setcookie('MYCOOKIE', '', -1, '/') ?? '';
```

```
!isset($_COOKIE['MYCOOKIE']) ?: setcookie('MYCOOKIE', '', -1, '/');
```