# Browser remembering cookies even if not supposed to

Tags: php, cookies, browser

I have built my logging in and out system but it seems to not work correctly in some browsers like chrome and firefox. The problem is that the browsers remember cookies even if they're meant to expire at session end.
Does anyone have a solution for that?

I'd just like to note that creating another cookie to monitor if it's supposed to remember or not is not a valid solution, there must be a more professional way.

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**: I apologize I got confused. I'm not unsetting the cookie at all, the browser is supposed to destroy it when it's closed but it doesn't. That's the problem

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12491756/unset-cookies-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the expiration date to the past

```
// set the expiration date to one hour ago
setcookie ("cookie", "", time() - 3600);
```

See [this example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php#example-4377) from php manuals.

**EDIT:**

To delete cookies when the browser or the tab is closed, you can use javascript onunload.

```
<script>
    window.onunload=function()
    {
        document.cookie = 'cookie =; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
    }
</script>
```

It will set the cookie expiration date to the past, on page unload.

Comment: @php_nub_qq, 0 It's not exactly a time value

Comment: That would not work in all browsers and in those that will it will delete cookies on tab close which is not what I need. How can this be such a big issue I'm going to cry soon!

Comment: @php_nub_qq maybe you would have to use [session cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php).

Comment: That was my last option, I was hoping I was going to get any other easier workaround but guess that's what I'd have to go with. Thank you for your effort! +rep

Answer (score 1):

To delete a cookie you need to set a negative time.

```
setcookie('cookie', '', time() - 3600);
```

Answer (score 1):

Like [PHP Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) says:

> If set to 0, or omitted, the cookie will expire at the end of the
>   session (when the browser closes)

This is the idea of PHP but some Browsers don't do that. Just set a negative Time like

```
setcookie("cookie", "", time() - 10);
```

and it works.

Comment: which is what I'm trying to do, but it doesn't expire. I edited my question I apologize

Comment: and you are closing your browser? Not just only a tab? Think that could be a potential mistake, although i didn't test this scenario