# PHP can't unset cookies

Tags: php, cookies

I can't figure out why I can't remove a cookie or it's value:

I have simple log in script, when user enters correct login details, this is

```
setcookie('logged', $admin['username'], time()+60*60*24*365);
```

Also, session_start() is present on all pages.

When I want to log off a user, the following happens:

```
if($page=='logoff') {
    setcookie('logged', "", time() - 3600);
    unset($_COOKIE['logged']); // tried also this
    session_destroy();
    $_SESSION=null;
    header("Location: index.php"); // if this is removed, the code below acts like there's no $_COOKIE['logged'] or it's empty (until refresh)
}
```

Once it gets redirected to index.php the $_COOKIE['logged'] is back with the old value, like something would set it again (nothing does for sure, I even removed the one and only login cookie set line)

I couldn't find a solution in similar questions. Tested in chrome and IE.

Comment: How about setting the time to 0 when you are setting the cookie?

Comment: check your browser time setting against server time, or give it `-100000` instead of `-3600` to make sure it is also past for the server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete/unset a cookie on php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341487/how-to-delete-unset-a-cookie-on-php)

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12491756/unset-cookies-php

Comment: I couldn't find an answer on these similar topics, I've tried what they suggested.

Comment: setcookie("logged", "", time()-100000, '/', 'domain.com'); doesn't change anything, after refresh the cookie is back. tested on several browsers.

Comment: @b0s3 unfortunately this didn't change anything. Also, I thought I can remove a cookie no matter on what term it was set.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "unset" a cookie. "Expire" it by setting it to a value in the past:

```
<?php
// set the expiration date to one hour ago
setcookie("logged", "", time() - 3600);
?>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp

Comment: Try to avoid w3schools.